# OSX: How to make whole extension as hidden file by default?

Tags: macos, finder

As far as I know windows has this feature. For example .DS_Store is hidden in osx by default. I want to make .pyc files hidden too, or *.tmp files..

Comment: Windows does _not_ hide files with certain extensions. Explorer only hides those with Hidden or System attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X hides files and folders that start with a dot '.', by default.

There are 3rd party applications to hide other files too, like [MacHider](http://macpaw.com/machider)

I'm not aware of programs that do this, but you can always try to find more on google.

**Update**

I found another solution, in Terminal:
`chflags hidden file/folder`

This hides the file or folder from Finder. `nohidden` restores the visibility.

You could make an applescript, which hides all `.pyc` files in current folder, and add it to your toolbar.  Or you could just run the command to recurse your whole filesystem (though that's generally not a good idea)